# EJS template is stripping brackets from array

Tags: json, express, ejs, stringify

I have an array contained in a JSON object that I'm passing into an express JS template and it seems like it's losing the brackets somewhere along the way.

When I console.log(JSON.stringify(theJSONObject)) what I see is:

```
[["2016-12-01","20.65"],["2016-12-02","20.46"],["2016-12-05","21.85"],["2016-12-06","20.57"],["2016-12-07","22.10"],["2016-12-08","21.55"],["2016-12-09","21.72"],["2016-12-12","21.54"],["2016-12-13","22.30"],["2016-12-14","21.79"],["2016-12-15","21.29"],["2016-12-16","20.92"],["2016-12-19","20.85"],["2016-12-20","21.79"],["2016-12-21","22.30"],["2016-12-22","22.14"],["2016-12-23","21.91"],["2016-12-27","21.29"],["2016-12-28","21.02"],["2016-12-29","21.06"],["2016-12-30","20.83"]]
```

However, when I feed theJSONObject into the EJS template, all of the brackets are disappearing and all I see in the HTML itself is

```
"2016-12-01","20.65","2016-12-02","20.46","2016-12-05","21.85","2016-12-06","20.57","2016-12-07","22.10","2016-12-08","21.55","2016-12-09","21.72","2016-12-12","21.54","2016-12-13","22.30","2016-12-14","21.79","2016-12-15","21.29","2016-12-16","20.92","2016-12-19","20.85","2016-12-20","21.79","2016-12-21","22.30","2016-12-22","22.14","2016-12-23","21.91","2016-12-27","21.29","2016-12-28","21.02","2016-12-29","21.06","2016-12-30","20.83"
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

JS must have been confused because the numbers were being read in as strings. When I changed them to numbers (i.e. 25 instead of "25") then reading in the arrays worked fine.